# How to implement the welcome page animation of appflow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

Below image is from AppFlow welcome page animation.

Not launch image, this is just part of welcome page , part of.... not all welcome page and I can't show the animation here, so I screen shot some frames of this animation and rearrange here.

I am sure that is not a gif or any image animation, should finished by objc code. Anyone could give me some thread or sample code will be great!

Thanks

[image: AppFlow welcome page animation]

Comment: You want to show this image as welcome screen in App?

Comment: Sorry @Vishal ,my bad, I updated my question, please ...

Comment: If you show frame in welcome screen or any kind of animation picture then perhaps it causing problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of displaying animations in iOS. For the animation you described above, I would recommend making one PNG image per frame. Then you can display the animation in a `UIImageView` similar to below:

```
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"], nil];
imageView.animationDuration = 1;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

Place the `UIImageView` on the welcome view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but I am pretty sure that AppFlow does not implement by any image, they do this animation by native code. So do you know any thread do this by native code?

Comment: Really? That looks like a real pain to create by code... I would look into basic circle drawing on iOS, and then look into animating the movement of the center of the circle. Unless you specifically have to program the animation, you would save a lot of time by just creating individual frames with Photoshop.

Comment: hehe, you are right, I'll try your solution, later update you. thanks a lot!

Comment: well, I tried, it works, but I have to prepare many jpg images for the animation, waste many space. so I prefer learn the one you motioned above, the "draw each element" solution. Do you have any thread where I can start with draw elements and animate them? Thanks